# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.setDisabled after Spring Security 4 upgrade

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security, upgrade

We upgraded our application to `spring security 4` from `spring security 3`.

It works fine other than when accessing views with input tags with attributes read only or disabled.

The following exception for example gets thrown when trying to display one of the offending forms:

> [org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.setDisabled(Ljava/lang/String;)V] with root cause
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.setDisabled(Ljava/lang/String;)

I am unable to reproduce the issue in our *dev environment*.

Dependencies are managed with Maven.
The `.war` is deployed on *Tomcat 7* running on a cluster of 2 servers.

Someone suggested it is a *classpath issue* and there may be *Spring 3* classes still hanging around and being loaded in different order in different environments.  But our `pom` file doesn't reference any *Spring 3* jars as far as I can tell.

Has anyone encountered this or something like this before and managed to resolve it?

Comment: It seems org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.setDisabled(String) not there in your project.Could you paste your pom.xml file

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:tree` to see all dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your tomcat installation has cached your compiled jsps in its work directory and the upgrade probably requires a re-compilation of the jsps in order to pick up the Spring 4 changes.

Try stopping tomcat, removing the work directory and restarting to see if that resolves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your application using old spring framework because in spring f/w 4 doesn't have setDisable(String) method .It is having setDisable(boolean).See spring f/w 4 doc http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/AbstractHtmlInputElementTag.html#setDisabled-boolean-

Please check your pom .xml and if it is ok then do mvn clean.

Comment: Thank you Pankaj. This helped. We've managed to reproduce it in dev now and isolated the cause to the Tomcat container.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue right now after upgrading to spring 4.  I noticed that the error does not occur when using tcServer in STS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by looking at the JSTL code in the JSP.  Are you setting a value other than true or false?  I was setting an attribute value to "readonly" (a string!).  But this is no longer allowed. Only "true" or "false" can be used.  See my update below:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${canEdit eq 'true'}">
        <c:set var="isTabReadonly" value="false" />
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
       <c:set var="isTabReadonly" value="readonly" /> // Change to "true"
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jenkins, completely delete the contents of the build directory prior to a build. Especially if you made major changes like we did. Don't trust Maven through Jenkins to always tell you the truth.

We had this same issue after upgrading from Spring 3.2 on Java 1.7 to Spring 4.3.x on Java 1.8. Everything worked great in our local environment (WebSphere Liberty Profile 17, jsp-2.2, servlet-3.0), but failed with this error in JSPs in the remote environment (WebSphere 8.5.5.9 Base, jsp-2.2, servlet-3.0).

Answer (score 0):

you can change: From `readonly="true"` to `readonly="${true}"` and false all project.